# Keep focus on input type text/search on keypress

Tags: javascript

I've written a simple input of type text, but when I press enter while my cursor is inside the textbox, it looses the focus. How can I ignore enter key to stop losing focus from the text box? I tried doing something like this:

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="keepFocus($event)" />
```

and keepFocus() is a method:

```
keepFocus(e) {
 e.target.select();
}
```

But this method is called everytime I press a key, which is not very efficient. Is there a better solution to handle this behavior?

Comment: Can't really reproduce that, are you sure this input isn't inside a form that is being submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You capture just the enter key, and prevent default when it's pressed

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by getting the **keyCode** (that **e parameter** use).

I mean, use this:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm

And this:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/event_preventdefault.asp

Something like this would be fine:

```js
    function keepFocus(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
             e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" keyup="keepFocus" />
```

This will prevent that you lost the focus when enter key is pressed!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do the job.

First, reput the focus to the input when the user click "Enter":

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="keepFocus(event);" id="teste" />
function keepFocus(e) {
    if (e.key=="Enter") {
      var teste = document.getElementById ("teste");
      teste.focus ();
  }
}
```

Second, prevent the default behavior of the text field:

```
function keepFocus(e) {
   if (e.key=="Enter") {
     e.preventDefault ();
  }
}
```

I think the second way is better because you do not have to add an id to your input.